# How to insert HTML as Text

Tags: javascript, html

I want HTML, for example, `<p>`, to show show as just that, in plain text, and not interpreted by the browser as an actual tag.

I know JQuery has .html and .text, but how is this done in raw JS?

There are functions like encodeURIComponent that encodes `<p>` to `%3Cp%3E` but if I just put that into HTML, it interprets it literally as `%3Cp%3E`.

So there are also things like `&gt;` and `&lt;`, they work but I can't find any JavaScript functions that escapes & unescapes from this.

Is there a correct way to show HTML as text with raw JavaScript?

Comment: I personally use the deprecated but working tag [XMP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/xmp) like this: `document.getElementById('someDiv').innerHTML='<xm'+'p><h1>Here is some <i>HTML</i></h1></xmp>'`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There's no need to escape the characters. Simply use `createTextNode`:

```
var text = document.createTextNode('<p>Stuff</p>');
document.body.appendChild(text);
```

See a working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/tZ3Xj/.

This is exactly how jQuery does it ([line 43 of jQuery 1.5.2](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.5.2/src/manipulation.js)):

```
return this.empty().append( (this[0] && this[0].ownerDocument || document).createTextNode( text ) );
```

Comment: Do you know why Prototype would be doing it the way that they are if this (better looking) technique works?

Comment: @thirtydot, does Prototype use escaping when inserting text into the DOM or is that just a utility function? I can imagine escaping to have its uses elsewhere.

Comment: Maybe createTextNode does escaping itself? Anyway, that's the function I need. Thanks.

Comment: .innerText will create and append the text node for you.

Answer (score 10):

The function used by Prototype looks like a good start:

http://www.prototypejs.org/api/string/escapeHTML

```
function escapeHTML() {
    return this.replace(/&/g,'&amp;').replace(/</g,'&lt;').replace(/>/g,'&gt;');
}
```

Version more suited to use outside Prototype:

```
function escapeHTML(html) {
    return html.replace(/&/g,'&amp;').replace(/</g,'&lt;').replace(/>/g,'&gt;');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use aslo `innerText` from most of DOM elements:

```
document.getElementById('some').innerText = "There can be <b> even HTML tags </b>";
```

The tags will not be formatted. You can aslo use `\n` for new line and more codes  (`\t`, `\u2623`...). If you want aslo to use fixed-size characters you can use easy `<pre>` tag.

Answer (score 2):

This is a job for the method [createTextNode](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/met_document_createtextnode.asp)

```
var target div = document.getElementById('div1');
targetDiv.appendChild(document.createTextNode('<p>HelloWorld</p>'));
```

Answer (score 2):

i suggest to use pre tag of html

and you can convert your using [this link](http://www.felgall.com/htmlt47.htm)

e.g if you copy

```
<p>Hi </p>
```

it will give you converted code as...

```
&lt;p&gt;Hi &lt;/p&gt;
```

Just copy and paste above code in pre and it will work fine...