# How to append html like plain text to page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have `<li>` in DOM, want to insert string with some HTML like plain text. But it appends with html. Sorry for bad English.

Example

```
<li></li> - empty list element
```

I want to append string `<script>alert(1)</script>` to li like text, without execute.

Comment: You want to add javascript to the HTML but don't want it to get executed?

Comment: @SaranshKataria i want to append it like plain text, to have <script> tag like plain text too

Comment: Use HTML entities: `&lt;script&gt;` and so on… Script elements inserted using *innerHTML* are not executed.

Comment: Do you mean you have a string that contains `HTML` that you want to output as plain text?

Comment: @RobG it must be text <script>

Comment: @QuodNephilim—which is exactly what `&lt;script&gt;` will produce if inserted as HTML.

Comment: I want to have text '<script>' on page

Comment: Probably a duplicate of [*show HTML as plain text*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16717513/show-html-as-plain-text) or [*How to insert HTML as Text*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5617260/how-to-insert-html-as-text).

Comment: @RobG you are right, but this question is different from them.

Comment: @ahsanayub—given that the accepted answer is identical to one of the answers at [*How to insert HTML as Text*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42403369/257182), I think it's a duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `innerText`, like so:

```js
document.querySelector('li').innerText += '<script>alert(1)<\/script>';
```

```html
<li></li>
```

However, remember that you will have to escape certain characters.

Comment: It's error in your snippet.

Comment: @QuodNephilim Indeed, I fixed it, refresh to see it.

Comment: Best answer, thanks. Maybe you know how to concat it?

Comment: @QuodNephilim What you want to concatenate?

Comment: basically `document.querySelector('li').innerText = document.querySelector('li').innerText + '<script>alert(1)<\/script>';`  but you should put it into a variable

Comment: @SteveKirsch `+=` would do the job as well, updated, thanks for the heads up!

Comment: Do not use innerText here. What you want is textContent. Since you are *getting* (`+=`)  innerText will trigger a reflow + will return only the visible part of the text if overflow.

Comment: @Kaiido can you explain this point a bit?

Comment: @ahsanayub Didn't I already? innerText is CSS aware, and at getting returns only the visible part of the element's textContent. So when you call its getter, the browser will have to perform a reflow (so it knows what's the visible textContent at this time is). And in case the node has some hidden textContent, you'll miss this hidden part.